# Runnable JAR Java-Prolog

Tags: java, jar, prolog

I'm developing a game with Java-Prolog connection, and I'm having trouble when I export the Runnable jar.
It works fine when I run the jar on my computer, but when I try to run it on another computer I get this:

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jpl in java.library.path at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source) at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source) at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)

I tried to copy the jpl.jar into my project folder, but it still not working on another computer.

How can I export it so anyone can run it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UnsatisfiedLinkError is thrown when an application attempts to load a native library like .so in Linux, .dll on Windows or .dylib in Mac and that library does not exist. Specifically, in order to find the required native library, the JVM looks in both the PATH environment variable and the java.library.path system property.

Every computer that needs to run that jar needs to have that library properly configured either in PATH environment variable or the java.library.path, and the library needs to exist in that computer, so try installing it in that computer before running it. Most games do this.